# Can a GET method be seen as POST method on server side?

Tags: php, curl

Is there a way to use a `GET` parameter and make the server see it as `POST` parameter? (like make some special encoding on the `get`)

ex: `http://example.com?id=100`

```
echo $_POST['id']; // sends 100
```

Comment: You could do something like `$_POST = $_GET;`, but that will **erase** the previous content of `$_POST`. Does that help?

Comment: @FirstOne If the server received a `GET` request, then `$_POST[]` should be null. Any refference, creates it.

Comment: @Bonatti What I meant was, if the OP is using something like `action="page.php?id=123" method="POST"`. That would send the other form fields too, so they would get replaced

Comment: Also `curl tag is there in the question` which is completely confusing?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible as mentioned in other answers but there is another way in which you can use

```
$_REQUEST
```

Just in case if you're not sure about the parameters if they are coming as POST or GET.

For further details: [PHP $_REQUEST](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php)

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know if that is possible, but you could try some *hack* and do it like this:

```
$_POST = $_GET;
```

*But beware*: **All** `$_POST` data will be **REPLACED** by `$_GET` data.

---

Example of the problem:

*get*:

```
Array
(
    [id] => 123
)
```

*post*:

```
Array
(
    [name] => FirstOne
)
```

*post* AFTER `$_POST = $_GET;`:

```
Array
(
    [id] => 123
)
```

*(Notice that it removed the previous value(s) from post: `name`)*

Comment: I posted this cause I had it typed for a long time waiting for the OP's response. They disapeared, so I'll leave it here in case someone else needs it.